# What jsRender tags accept tmpl?

Tags: jsrender

I know that **for** and **if** accept the template via *tmpl*.  Does **else**?  Any other statements accept *tmpl*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any tag that accepts block content will allow you to write `{{foo ...}}...{{/foo}}` or `{{foo ... tmpl=expr/}}`. Expression support in `expr` is very flexible. For example it can be `"myTemplateName"` or `~a.b.getTheTemplate()` returning a compiled template, or `"someHTMLmarkup"`.

That includes `{{else tmpl=...}}` and there is an example in the unit tests here: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/test/unit-tests/tests-jsrender-no-jquery.js#L73.